# Services is not calling using local WAMP in Android

Tags: php, android, webservices-client

I want to know that how to create a virtual host using WAMP.

I have made a webservice in PHP for my Android application and hosted it on a local WAMP server.

When I call the webservice using application, it gives an error

> 01-24 12:51:14.685:
>   WARN/System.err(476):
>   java.net.ConnectException:
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection
>   refused

This is an error when I am calling the webservice from my local WAMP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to a webserver running on the same development machine as your Android emulator?  If so, from within the Android emulator try using **10.0.2.2** instead of localhost.

For more information about why this is necessary, read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, there is a button at the top of the wamp menu that gives you to set the server "online", which gives you to obtain the IP of the server.

Did you tried that?

BTW can you post the call to the web service so we can have more details?